# Multiple parameters in an Node/Express RESTful request?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I was looking at how to implement a RESTful API in Node, and it seems pretty easy, but I cannot get it to take multiple parameters.

For instance `example.com/api/foo/bar`.

I have tried

```
app.get('/try/:foo/:bar', routes.try);
```

With:

```
exports.try = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { foo: req.params.foo, bar: req.params.bar, title: 'try'})
};
```

But this is getting me a 404.

Comment: can you show your file structure and/or your whole file which you're declaring your routes in? I just tested this out and ran `console.log(req.params);` in my callback and got `[ foo: 'x', bar: 'y' ]`. You must have an error somewhere else.

Comment: When I shortened to to /try/:foo, I got the expected result. I shall edit my post, however.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Node.js or Express doesn't like trailing slashes when you declare routes.

I was doing:

```
app.get('/try/:foo/:bar/', routes.try);
```

Which resulted in an error.

```
app.get('/try/:foo/:bar', routes.try);
```

Worked fine, however.